# Генерация дороги для раннера unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine-4, blueprint

Я сейчас делаю бесконечную генерацию дороги в анриале для раннера, но возник вопрос. Я использую такой метод подгружаю дорогу и затем через задержку удаляю. Является ли это оптимальным вариантом или лучше использовать пул объектов?

Comment: Какие недостатки вы видите в текущей реализации?

Comment: Когда я работал на unity с этой же задачей мне советовали реализовывать генерацию через пул, так как метод, который использую я влияет на ресурсы, НО это было на unity.

Comment: По-этому и решил спросить.

Comment: *"По-этому и решил спросить"* - решили спросить какие недостатки *мы* видим в *вашей* текущей реализации?? Бред )

Comment: Я решил убедиться, что моё решение оптимальное и на мобильных устройствах будет работать нормально.

Comment: В вашем вопросе катастрофически мало деталей, для того чтобы дать хоть сколько-нибудь обоснованный ответ.

Comment: Хм, вопрос заключается в следующем. Мне лучше использовать пул или метод "создани и удаления" для генерации бесконечной дороги.

Comment: @RedFox тогда вопрос будет закрыт как тот на который можно ответить только субъективно, лучше напишите так: "Какой метод работает быстрее и эффективнее для генерации бесконечной дороги, создание пула или метод создания и удаления?"

Comment: Смотря насколько создание-удаление для вас более или менее простая и/или затратная операция по сравнению с пулом. Судя по всему, пока у вас нету даже результатов профилирования, и любое изменение будет тыком пальцем в небо и/или экономией на спичках. Разработка обычно ведется по принципу "что конкретно надо добавить или исправить", а не "как бы пофеншуйнее расставить модули" )

Comment: Точно, нужно пройтись профайлером.